# Where to check security in Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, security, symfony-3.3

I write an application with `Symfony 3.3` without `FOSUserBundle`.
The typical flow is one of:

- Controller => Service => Repository => Entity
- Command => Service => Repository => Entity

Initially I put all `isGranted` and `denyAccessUnlessGranted` calls inside services, but this is getting messy when I use services from commands. I hacked the commands by authenticating users via `get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token)`, but it looks kind of messy.

Since I didn't find anything beyond 'hello world' examples, I am asking this here:

**Are there any best practices on where to execute the security checks**? Should they be inside controllers and commands or inside services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put security checks in the controller.
Let's say that you have a controller action that calls some service for modifying some entity. That modification can be done only by a specific kind of user.
It makes no sense to pass a user from controller to the service, and then check if the user is granted to perform some action.
Just cut it at the very beginning.